# Simple inequality question involing four numbers

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c,d$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $e > \max(b,d)$. Does $|a/e - c/e| < |a/b -c/d|$ hold?

I can't construct a counterexample and I don't know where to start with the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick $a, b, c, d = 0, -1, 1, -1$ and $e = 1/2$.

Left hand side is 
$$
|\frac{ 0}{1/2} - \frac{1}{1/2}| = 2.
$$
Right hand side is 
$$
|\frac{ 0}{-1} - \frac{1}{-1}| = 1.
$$
So your inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. I edited my question.

Comment: It looks as if you made another mistake, since the letter $d$ is now missing in the inequality.